# Java: how to change code from button click to onload

Tags: java, swing, onload

I have the following code that works fine, but i want the names of people to show on load, instead of when the button is clicked by the user.
How would i implement this?

```
public class NameSwing implements ActionListener {

    private JTextArea tf = new JTextArea(20, 20);
    private JFrame f = new JFrame("names");
    private JButton b = new JButton("view");
    static String fullName;

    public NameSwing() {
        f.add(new JLabel("Name"));
        tf.setEditable(true);
        f.add(tf);

        b.addActionListener(this);
        f.add(b);

        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.setSize(600, 600);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == b) {
            tf.setText(fullName);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        NameSwing nameSwing = new NameSwing();

        Names t = new Names();
        t.OpenFile();
        t.ReadFile();
        t.CloseFile();

        fullName = Names.fullName;
    }

}
```

`Names` class:

```
package names;

public class Names {

    Scanner scan;
    static String Firstname = null;
    static String Surname;
    static String Fullname;
    static String fullName;
    String myArray[];

    public void OpenFile() {
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File("/Users/nikhilpatel/NetBeansProjects/Names/src/names/test.txt"));
            System.out.println("File found!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    }

    public void ReadFile() {
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            Firstname = scan.next();
            Surname = scan.next();
            Fullname += Firstname + " " + Surname + "\n";
            fullName = Fullname.replace("null", "");

            System.out.println(fullName);
        }

    }

    public void CloseFile() {
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1)  Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.  2) `Fullname += Firstname + " " + Surname + "\n";`  Don't hard-code EOL.  Java has a property for it.  3) Given the form of the data, I would tend to display it in a `JTable`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    NameSwing nameSwing = new NameSwing();

    Names t = new Names();
    t.OpenFile();
    t.ReadFile();
    t.CloseFile();

    fullName = Names.fullName;
    tf.setText(fullName);
}
```

Just add the `actionPerformed` stuff in. Or make a new method (called buttonClick or something) and call it 1.) in `actionPerformed` and 2.) at the end of `main`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several alternatives, depending on how "elegant" you want to achieve the result, one could be to refactor your code extracting the `actionPerformed` method body to a more independant method, then in `main` invoke that public method:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   fillTextArea();
}

public void fillTextArea() {
    // You can drop this line, this Listener is registered for 'b', so 'b' 
    // is the only one who fires the ActionEvent, not need to recheck 
    //
    // if (e.getSource() == b) {

    tf.setText(fullName);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    NameSwing nameSwing = new NameSwing();

    Names t = new Names();
    t.OpenFile();
    t.ReadFile();
    t.CloseFile();

    fullName = Names.fullName;

    // Invoke the new method
    nameSwing.fillTextArea();
}
```

Another approach (and a tricky one), is to simple call the [method `doClick`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29) from `b` like this:

```
// Add a getter for 'b' 
public JButton getButton() { 
    return b;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    NameSwing nameSwing = new NameSwing();

    Names t = new Names();
    t.OpenFile();
    t.ReadFile();
    t.CloseFile();

    fullName = Names.fullName;

    // This will simulate a 'click' on the button, loading the names 
    nameSwing.getButton().doClick();
}
```

Hope this helps